# bootstrap modal dynamic remote content based on parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am working on popups shown in bootstrap modal. I am creating buttons which are shown in table like this:

```
<button class = "sendbt btn btn-default" href="test.php?spz='.$row['id'].'" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><b>Test</b></button>
```

So remote content of button on every row of the table should be different based on $row['id'] - it is the variable from database and the table is created via php echo loop.
The problem is my modal popup shows always the content based on the first button i click and then after i close it, every other button in other rows shows the same content. It is not changing based on parameter. I need to reload the page, to show changed contents on different buttons. Is there a way to may this work, so every button in table would show the proper content based on my parameter without reloading the page every time?

Thank you for possible advices.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add custom attribute to button and remove the href attribute from button... make button with type button and assing the dynamic id to each button created in row like the following

```
<button type="button" class = "sendbt btn btn-default" data-id="$row['id']"><b>Test</b></button>
```

Now add click listener to button and find it data-id,then send ajax request and update the modal content with response:
write jquery for sending request to test.php page

```
$('body').on('click','.sendbt',function(){
     var data-id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $.ajax({
         dataType : 'html',
         'type': 'GET',
         'data' : {id:data-id},
          'url' : 'test.php',
          success : function(data){
            $('#myModal tbody-content').html(data);
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
},
          error : function(){
       console.log("There is an Error ....!")
}

});
});
```

in Your Test.php

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
   $query = mysql_query("select * from table_name where id=".$_REQUEST['id']);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['your_attribute'];
echo $content;
}
```

It will show the related content with respect to id your send in each request

Comment: Somehow this works only for first two buttons I click. The third button i click shows black screen with <div class="modal-backdrop in"></div> effect.

Comment: in your test.php print_r($row); i think there will be no data in database againt the id